# Regex Word at least 1 digit numbers and at least 2 letters

Tags: regex

Please assist with the proper RegEx matching. Word at least 1 digit numbers and at least 2 letters

```
These would be valid: 
1234567890aA
123A4567890a
A1234567890a
John12
qw123123
John20
20John
1aa

These would not:
1234567890A
1234567890
1234567a890
a1234567890
1a
```

Comment: `/[a-z]/ig` for letters and calculate the length, `/[0-9]/g` for numbers. Just use `&&` condition with both the matchings...

Comment: Is it that you want to match words within the input, or is it the entire input is a single word that must match like this

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, and then we help. We don't write it for you. Show us the actual code that you've tried, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a look ahead for each stipulation:

```
\b(?=\w*\d)(?=(?:\w*[a-zA-Z]){2})[\da-zA-Z]+\b
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/BmiZax1fOiawmu).

Comment: `\w` also matches underscore.  Where did you read in the OP that underscore is an allowed character?

Comment: @tim I knew you’d say that, and you’re wrong. The input only matches digits and letters, so the underscore of `\w` in the look ahead is irrelevant, but`\w` is the most convenient for ensuring the look ahead doesn’t run past the word boundary.

Answer (score 1):

@Tim Biegeleisen and @Bohemian♦ used look ahead.
I have another idea that does not use look ahead.

`\b.*([a-z]\d+[a-z]|[a-z]{2,}\d|\d[a-z]{2,}).*?\b` (with case insensitive option)

It is just expecting all three possible case.

1. letter, 1 or more digits, letter (ex: a1b, a12b)
2. 2 or more letters, digit (ex: ab1, abc1)
3. digit, 2 or more letters (ex: 1ab, 1abc)

It is not flexible than using look ahead because it will be difficult to expect all possible case when condition changed to 3 or more letters.

But much faster than using look ahead.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/38s3e7/1

Answer (score 0):

You could use the pattern `^(?=.*\d).*[A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z].*$`:

```js
var inputs = ["1234567890aA", "1234567890A"];
for (var i=0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
    if (/^(?=.*\d).*[A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z].*$/.test(inputs[i])) {
        console.log(inputs[i] + " => VALID");
    }
    else {
        console.log(inputs[i] + " => INVALID");
    }
}
```

Comment: OP asked for word match, not entire input

Comment: The OP's sample inputs implied (at least to me) that the regex test would be applied against isolated words.  It is trivial to change the `^` and `$` anchors in my answer to word boundaries.

Comment: I changed `^` and `$` to `\b` and `\b` as you said. but it was not success because `.` consumes all including `\b`.  So testing `1234567890aA 1234567890A` text with `\b(?=.*\d).*[A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z].*\b` pattern select whole line. It must select first word only.

Comment: Please add sample data to your question which actually reflects your real question.  I have answered based on what I saw.